# What is an idiomatic way to enumerate the alphabet in go?

Tags: go

This might be the best way:

```
for i := 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++ {
    fmt.Println(string(i))
}
```

Is there a better / idiomatic approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for _, c := range "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" {
  fmt.Println(string(c))
}
```

Comment: Useful if you need to constrain your iterations to a certain subset of characters. Works with multibyte characters, too.

Answer (score 1):

This question's answers will arguably be mostly opinion-based so not really a good fit for stackoverflow, yet the way you describe is indeed acceptable as an optimal solution for the lower-case english alphabet in idiomatic Go. Other alphabets will be more complicated to formulate.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better / idiomatic approach?

No.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
for i := 97 ; i < 123 ; i++ {
    fmt.Printf("%c",i)
}
```

[Live Demo](http://play.golang.org/p/J6-5Ym9kSa)